# MongoDB Container Connection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

This is my first time trying MongoDB.  I'm just trying to simply connect to it successfully.  I'm following the W3 tutorial here:  https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb.asp

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - /home/username/mongodb/data:/data/db
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8089:8081
```

With that, the mongo-express UI seems to work fine.  I can create a database etc...

but, this does not work:

create_db_test.js

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mytestdb";

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Database created!");
  db.close();
});
```

........

```
node create_db_test.js
```

and this just hangs.  There's just a blank line on the command line and it does nothing.  The database is not created.  The log output from the container looks like this:

```
mongodb-mongo-1          | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-27T16:04:20.449+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"172.18.0.1:39946","uuid":"abbbc8ad-fceb-4a6b-b6e4-12d123a837b7","connectionId":2,"connectionCount":2}}
mongodb-mongo-1          | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-27T16:04:20.469+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"172.18.0.1:39946","client":"conn2","doc":{"driver":{"name":"nodejs","version":"5.5.0"},"platform":"Node.js v18.12.1, LE","os":{"name":"linux","architecture":"arm64","version":"6.1.25-37.47.amzn2023.aarch64","type":"Linux"}}}}
mongodb-mongo-1          | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-27T16:04:30.983+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"172.18.0.1:60246","uuid":"47895fe4-78f3-4401-a886-4d5ef832c66b","connectionId":3,"connectionCount":3}}
mongodb-mongo-1          | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-27T16:04:30.985+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn3","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"172.18.0.1:60246","client":"conn3","doc":{"driver":{"name":"nodejs","version":"5.5.0"},"platform":"Node.js v18.12.1, LE","os":{"name":"linux","architecture":"arm64","version":"6.1.25-37.47.amzn2023.aarch64","type":"Linux"}}}}
```

When I interrupt create_db_test.js with Ctrl-C, the container log suggests that the connection has been open the whole time and is now ended:

```
mongodb-mongo-1          | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-27T16:05:10.053+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn3","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"172.18.0.1:60246","uuid":"47895fe4-78f3-4401-a886-4d5ef832c66b","connectionId":3,"connectionCount":2}}
mongodb-mongo-1          | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-27T16:05:10.053+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20883,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"Interrupted operation as its client disconnected","attr":{"opId":620}}
mongodb-mongo-1          | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-27T16:05:10.054+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"172.18.0.1:39946","uuid":"abbbc8ad-fceb-4a6b-b6e4-12d123a837b7","connectionId":2,"connectionCount":1}}
```

I've also tried this (where "mydb" is already created through mongo-express) with the same result:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/";

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("mydb");
    var myobj = { name: "Company Inc", address: "Highway 37" };
    dbo.collection("customers").insertOne(myobj, function(err, res) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("1 document inserted");
      db.close();
    });
});
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: If you _insert_ a _document_ in a _collection_ in that _database_, does it work and is the _database_ / _collection_ created?

Comment: I'm wondering if better success could be achieved by following MongoDB's [Node.js Quick Start](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/quick-start/) and adapting it to your MongoDB server.

Comment: ... beginning with Node.js driver version 5.00: [_"... removed support for callbacks in favor of a Promise-only public API."_](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/releases).

Answer (score 1):

Per @rickhg12hs suggestion, support for callbacks has been removed.  The following code works:

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
const uri = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/";

const client = new MongoClient(uri);

async function run() {
  try {
    console.log("Trying insert....");
    const database = client.db('mydb');
    const customers = database.collection('customers');
    const myobj = { name: "Company Inc", address: "Highway 37" };
    const result = await customers.insertOne(myobj);
    console.log(result);
  } finally {
    // Ensures that the client will close when you finish/error
    await client.close();
    console.log("Done.");
  }
}
run().catch(console.dir);
```